# ASP.NET 4.8 Feature unavailable in IIS 8.5 (Windows Server 2012 R2)

Tags: asp.net, iis, windows-server-2012-r2, .net-4.8

Windows Server 2012 R2, IIS 8.5, .NET 4.8 is installed (verified via the Registry, see screen-shot).

On my Windows 10 machine, I see the option to select the ASP.NET 4.8 feature from the "Turn Windows Features on or off" dialog. However, in the Add Server Role wizard on Windows 2012 R2, I only see ASP.NET 4.5 option listed. See screen-shot for comparison.

My question: Is that normal for Windows Server 2012 R2 to only show an ASP.NET 4.5 option? Even if a higher version of the .NET Framework (e.g. 4.8) is installed?

[image: .NET Framework 4.8 is installed]

[image: Feature Comparison side-by-side]

Comment: Server Manager always shows the bundled 4.x name, instead of the actual 4.y name you upgraded. That's a known bugs since 2008.

Comment: Ah, ok thanks @LexLi. You can answer and I'll mark it as the answer.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As Windows Server default installation ships with a specific .NET Framework (4.5 for example), Microsoft hard coded the version names (like .NET Framework 4.5) in certain UI elements, such as Server Manager.

That becomes a critical problem, when you upgrade that to a newer .NET Framework release (such as 4.6), because the installer does not update those hard coded names.

This issue has been well known for years, so your only option is to accept it.

Answer (score 0):

My solution is install visual stuido on IIS host and Change properties to 4.8 Framewoker version (https://www.grapecity.com/kb/how-to-change-the--net-framework-version-in-visual-studio)

This solution make my project can run System.IO.Compression.ZipFile .
the ref cant run on default 4.5 version.